# Jquery Target a tag in the third child of previous sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not so great with traversing in jquery.  Here is my markup:

```
<div class="row planarea">

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h1>Agera Fixed Advantage 12</h1>
    Fixed Price - 12 Months<br>
    Utility: Con Edison
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span class="price">$0.0799</span> <span class="killowats">/ kWh</span>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <a class="nolink showmore" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#24moscollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="24moscollapse">
      <div class="selectdetails">
        Details <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
    </a>

    <label >
      <input type='radio' name="prefs" class="hidecheck" value="mail">
      <span></span>
    </label>

  </div>


</div><!--row-->

<div class="row collapse detailsrow" id="24moscollapse">
  <div class="col-xs-12 plandetailsbox">
    stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

what I want to do is something similar to this:

```
$('.detailsrow').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  $(this).prev().closest().("a.showmore").html('<div     class="selectdetails">Details <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up" aria-    hidden="true"></i></div>'); 
})
```

I can't seem to figure out how to target that a tag and it's getting kind of confusing.  I need to target what I believe is the a tag in the third child of the previous sibling for every repeated row of this information.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `.closest()` navigates up and the syntax is to have the selector inside the parens. I think you want `.find("selector")`.

Comment: thanks this is what I needed.  Works like a charm now :)

Comment: Yep, don't forget to mark Mojtaba's answer accepted if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

closest() finds the first parent. And closest(selector) finds the first selector matched parent.

Whereas, you are looking for a child. So, you can use find(selector).

Change this:

```
$(this).prev().closest().("a.showmore")
```

To this:

```
$(this).prev().find("a.showmore")
```

Comment: there was no answer until I posted one  anyways this is correct +1. Happy coding. :) . It will be great if you can explain a bit so the OP understands. Deleting mine

Comment: @bipen, no problem. I updated the answer. If you want to add more, feel free to edit my answer